# GET statuses/home_timeline Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to retrieve Twitter Timeline statuses using [API 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline):

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?count=10';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$tweets = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```

I expect when I receive the response and use `json_decode($tweets, true);`, size of result be 10. But it is 9!

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Presumably because there are only 9 tweets on the account

Comment: @Quentin I checked it. It is not the reason. Number of tweets are much more than 10 on my timeline.